# Как взять значение этого элемента в selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Я хотела бы взять значение перевода слова с этого сайта через selenium
https://www.deepl.com/ru/translator

[image]

но значение второго окна ( с переводом) не имеет значения.
Как его можно получить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через значение атрибута
String result= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='dl_translator']/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/textarea")).getAttribute("value");

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй использовать варианты перевода ниже

```
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='lmt__side_container lmt__side_container--source']/div[2]/div/textarea")).sendKeys("car");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        String result = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='lemma_content']/div/div/div[1]/h3/span/a")).getText();

        System.out.println("Text: " + result);
```

Comment: Нужно было через значение атрибута